# substring indexing and matching on json string arrays in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL with a jsonb field, defined as `json JSONB NOT NULL`. An example value of that json is a string array like the following

```json
{ "values": ["foo", "bar", "foobar"]}
```

For checking rows where `values` have a specific value, e.g. `foo`, using a query and an index like the following works fine and fast.

```sql
-- index
CREATE INDEX table_idx ON T USING gin ((json -> 'values'));
-- query
SELECT * from T where T.json->'values' ?| array['foo']
```

In order to support substring matching, I used the following indexes and queries

```sql
-- index
CREATE INDEX table_idx_trigram ON T USING gin ((json ->> 'values') gin_trgm_ops);
-- query
SELECT * from T 
where exists ( 
   select * from jsonb_array_elements_text(T.json->'values') values(elem) 
   where elem like '%foo%'
)
```

while the query works fine, the index I created does not get used and results in a full table scan. Is there a way I can formulate the query or the index better in order to improve the performance of the query?

-- update 1: added the output of the explain command

Here's the output of the explain command

```
"Seq Scan on public.T  (cost=0.00..50630.30 rows=18268 width=379) (actual time=1.384..66.731 rows=173 loops=1)"
"  Output: T.json"
"  Filter: (SubPlan 1)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 36364"
"  Buffers: shared hit=548 read=3863"
"  SubPlan 1"
"    ->  Function Scan on pg_catalog.jsonb_array_elements_text values  (cost=0.01..1.25 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=36537)"
"          Function Call: jsonb_array_elements_text((T.json -> 'values'::text))"
"          Filter: (values.elem ~~ '%foo%'::text)"
"          Rows Removed by Filter: 4"
"Planning Time: 0.114 ms"
"Execution Time: 66.771 ms"
```

Comment: Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statement? (in plain text)

Comment: yes, updated the query, I should have added that from the start

Comment: I doubt that there is an efficient way to do substring search in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Right, the index works on the thing that was indexed, not some manipulation of the thing indexed.

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT * from T 
where (json ->> 'values') like '%foo%' and exists ( 
   select * from jsonb_array_elements_text(T.json->'values') values(elem) 
   where elem like '%foo%'
)
```

Where the `exists` is still there is catch any false positives.  However, this method is liable to suffer false negatives, like if any of the values contain literal double quotes which get back-whacked when cast to text as part of a JSON array, but not when extracted as text from the same array.

Comment: Thanks! I had thought for something like this as a fallback. isn't there a way to define the index in a different way to make it work? The exact match index correctly indexes array items for containment, I thought there could be something like that for trigrams